# Can't figure out why im getting a syntax error

Tags: python

Im following a tutorial to code a game, as far as i can tell, my code is the same as the one in the tutorial, ive been working at this for about 45mins, and checked over the code twice, but here is the code

```
import pygame
import math
import random

# Intialize the Pygame
pygame.init()

# Create the Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Background
background = pygame.image.load("space.png")

# Title and Icon
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load("alien.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

# Player
playerImg = pygame.image.load("player.png")
playerX = 370
playerY = 480
playerX_change = 0

# Enemy
enemyImg = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []
num_of_enemies = 6

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyImg.append(pygame.image.load("enemy.png"))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(4)
    enemyY_change.append(30)

# Bullet

# Ready - You can't see the bullet on the screen

# Fire_ The bullet is currently moving
bulletImg = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bulletX = 0
bulletY = 480
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 15
bullet_state = "ready"
score = 0


def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemyImg[i], (x, y))


def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 16, y + 10))


def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False


# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Background image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        # If keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    # Checking for boundaries for space ship
    playerX += playerX_change

    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736

    # Enemy movement
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:
            enemyX_change[i] = 4
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:
            enemyX_change[i] = -4
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        # Collision
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = "ready"
            score += 1
            print(score)
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    # Bullet Movement
    if bulletY <= 0:
        bulletY = 480
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    player(playerX, playerY)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is the error im getting:

```
     line 70
        if distance < 27:
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Im new to python, so it might be something stupid that i forgot, but i cannot figure this out.

Comment: Count parentheses on the previous line.

Comment: The line before it is missing a closing parenthesis `)`.

Comment: Ok i guess i was right, it was stupid lol

Comment: Some time ago I suggested the idea of a bot that answered every question with "syntax error" in the title with: "You might have unbalanced parentheses on the previous line.". I still like that idea. ;)

Comment: yeah they need to be more descriptive when you get a error

Comment: Be careful, it seems that you're combining multiple naming conventions. It's best to just stick to `lower_case_with_underscores` for functions and most variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a close bracket:

```
distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
```